# How to aggregate keyword field by a specific value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm looking for a solution to aggregate data by a specific value in a `keyword` field.

Here is the data:

```
"message" : "status: 123, msg: blablabla",
"message" : "start_at: 20190701, source: location_a",
"message" : "status: 456, msg: blabla",
"message" : "start_at: 20190701, source: location_b",
"message" : "status: 123, msg: blablablabla",
```

(`message` is that `keyword` field)

And, I queried this index by:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "status"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I got the result like:

```
{
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_index" : "2019.07.25",
      "_source" : {
        "message" : """status: 123, msg: blablabla""",
      }
    },
    {
      "_index" : "2019.07.25",
      "_source" : {
        "message" : """status: 456, msg: blabla""",
      }
    },
    {
      "_index" : "2019.07.25",
      "_source" : {
        "message" : """status: 123, msg: blablablabla""",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I wish to aggregate data by the value of `status`, e.g.:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "status" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "123" : {
          "doc_count" : 250
        },
        "456" : {
          "doc_count" : 248
        },
        "789" : {
          "doc_count" : 2356
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(There are more than 100+ different `state` in raw data.)

So, how can I aggregate these data?

(ps. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use painless script in the terms aggregation**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "def field = 'status: '; def msg = doc['message.keyword'].value; def start = msg.indexOf(field); def end = msg.indexOf(',', start); if(start > -1) {return msg.substring(start+field.length(), end)}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Output :

```
"aggregations": {
  "genres": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "123",
        "doc_count": 2
      },
      {
        "key": "456",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

At first the script find the location of `status:` using indexOf method and then find the immediate `,` These two index location used to extract the status value using substring method